# Method for maintaining access to a variable that is moved into a closure

Tags: rust, closures

I am trying to move values into a `ctrlc` closure, but update these same values in the main block until the Ctrl+C signal is seen. At which point the closure will call a function that displays some stats about the values.

Specifically, I am recreating `ping`. I have variables `requests` and `replies` that track the number of each that occurs during the program's life. When the user input Ctrl+C, the program will display the total requests, replies, and the percentage of packets lost.

Example:

```
fn ping(ip: IpAddr, frequency: u32) -> () {
    let requests = 0;
    let replies = 0;
    ctrlc::set_handler(move || calc_stats(requests, replies)).expect("");

    //each echo request increments request by 1
    //each echo reply increments replies by 1

    //eventually user enter Ctrl+C, the closure is called and in turn calc_stats is called
```

Now I know the code above will not work because requests and replies would be moved. But I tried using a Box and even Arc but run into an assortment of errors. The Box approach works when I clone:

```
let closure = {
        let crequests = requests.clone();
        let creplies = replies.clone();
        ctrlc::set_handler(move || calc_stats(crequests.clone(), creplies.clone(), &min, &max, &rtts))
        .expect("Could not calculate stats");
    };
```

But the requests and replies variables are still their initial values (0).

What is the ideal approach in this scenario?

Comment: You'll probably need the make the variables `Arc<Mutex<i32>>`

Comment: In case of a `i32` (or other primitives that have a `AtomicXX`) I'd use `AtomicI32` over `Mutex<i32>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Arc` is the correct move. However, it doesn't allow you to get an `&mut` to the contents, so you need an interior mutability construct, like [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html).

```rs
pub fn ping(ip: IpAddr, frequency: u32) {
    let requests = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let replies = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

    let state_clone = state.clone();
    ctrlc::set_handler(move || calc_stats(&requests, &replies)).unwrap();
}

fn calc_stats(requests: &Mutex<i32>, replies: &Mutex<i32>) {
    todo!()
}
```

It is a bit inefficient to have two mutexes here, so you could put all your state variables into a struct.

```rs
struct State {
    requests: u32,
    replies: u32,
}

impl State {
    fn new() -> Self {
        State {
            requests: 0,
            replies: 0,
        }
    }
}
```

And then wrap that `State` in a mutex. Here's a whole example, minus the actual pinging.

```rs
pub fn ping(ip: IpAddr, frequency: u32) {
    let state = Arc::new(Mutex::new(State::new()));

    let state_clone = state.clone();
    ctrlc::set_handler(move || calc_stats(&state_clone)).unwrap();

    do_things(&state, ip, frequency);
}

fn calc_stats(state: &Mutex<State>) {
    let state = state.lock().unwrap();
    println!("Requests: {}\nReplies: {}", state.requests, state.replies);
    std::process::exit(0);
}

fn do_things(state: &Mutex<State>, ip: IpAddr, frequency: u32) {
    loop {
        {
            println!("Request");
            let mut state = state.lock().unwrap();
            state.requests += 1;
        }
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        {
            println!("Reply");
            let mut state = state.lock().unwrap();
            state.replies += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Just ensure you leave the mutex unlocked at some point so that the `ctrlc` handler can read it.

A more performant implementation would use the [`Atomic*`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html) integers instead of `Mutex`, but `Mutex` is more general and easier to use.

Also some general advice, more errors does not necessarily mean your code is more incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I implemented the Arc/Mutex approach and it is working as intended.